# Why do I get run time error Reference at undefined variable?

Tags: fortran, runge-kutta, orbital-mechanics

I am using the Runge-Kutta 4th order method to integrate the motion of a point like satellite. The compilation of the program is OK. But when I try to run it Run time error 112

```
Reference at undefined variable,array element or function result (/UNDEF)
```

shows up at line 19. I have changed the loop condition many times and nothing changes. I am pretty sure I have declared every quantity that appears in line 19 (where I write the equation for K1). The code I am using is in Fortran 95.

The code:

```
program SatelliteMonopoleNoDrag

implicit none

real, external :: F1,F2,F3,F4

real :: t,x,y,u,v,K0,K1,K2,K3,M0,M1,M2,M3,N0,N1,N2,N3,P0,P1,P2,P3,h

print*, " Insert t0 "

read*, t

print*, " Insert x0 "

read*, x

print*, " Insert y0 "

read*, y

print*, " Insert u0 "

read*, u

print*, " Insert v0 "

read*, v

print*, " Insert h "

read*, h

do while (t<=86400)

  K0=h*F1(t,x,y,u,v)

  K1=h*F1(t+h/2.,x+K0/2.,y+M0/2.,u+N0/2.,v+P0/2.)

  K2=h*F1(t+h/2.,x+K1/2.,y+M1/2.,u+N1/2.,v+P1/2.)

  K3=h*F1(t+h,x+K2,y+M2,u+N2,v+P2)

  M0=h*F2(t,x,y,u,v)

  M1=h*F2(t+h/2.,x+K0/2.,y+M0/2.,u+N0/2.,v+P0/2.)

  M2=h*F2(t+h/2.,x+K1/2.,y+M1/2.,u+N1/2.,v+P1/2.)

  M3=h*F2(t+h,x+K2,y+M2,u+N2,v+P2)

  N0=h*F3(t,x,y,u,v)

  N1=h*F3(t+h/2.,x+K0/2.,y+M0/2.,u+N0/2.,v+P0/2.)

  N2=h*F3(t+h/2.,x+K1/2.,y+M1/2.,u+N1/2.,v+P1/2.)

  N3=h*F3(t+h,x+K2,y+M2,u+N2,v+P2)

  P0=h*F4(t,x,y,u,v)

  P1=h*F4(t+h/2.,x+K0/2.,y+M0/2.,u+N0/2.,v+P0/2.)

  P2=h*F4(t+h/2.,x+K1/2.,y+M1/2.,u+N1/2.,v+P1/2.)

  P3=h*F4(t+h,x+K2,y+M2,u+N2,v+P2)

  x=x+(1/6.)*(K0+2*K1+2*K2+K3)

  y=y+(1/6.)*(M0+2*M1+2*M2+M3)

  u=u+(1/6.)*(N0+2*N1+2*N2+N3)

  v=v+(1/6.)*(P0+2*P1+2*P2+P3)

  t=t+h

  print*, " The values of t,x,y,u,v are " ,t,x,y,u,v

end do

print*, " The values of t,x,y,u,v are " , t,x,y,u,v

end



real function F1(t,x,y,u,v)

real :: t,x,y,u,v

F1=u

end



real function F2(t,x,y,u,v)

real :: t,x,y,u,v

F2=v

end



real function F3(t,x,y,u,v)

real, parameter :: G=6.674*(10.)**(-11)

real, parameter :: M=5.9722*10**(24)

real :: t,x,y,u,v

F3=-G*M*x/(sqrt(x**2+y**2))**3

end



real function F4(t,x,y,u,v)

real, parameter :: G=6.674*(10.)**(-11)

real, parameter :: M=5.9722*10**(24)

real :: t,x,y,u,v

F4=-G*M*y/(sqrt(x**2+y**2))**3

end
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Use the proper formatting for your code. You need to give us the the values you start from. Or just put them as fixed values into your code. Use [edit]. Also, use modules for your functions, to avoid many types of problems.

Comment: Also be aware that saying "Error 112" is meaningless. My compiler, for example, does not issue any numbers for the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

M0, M1, M2, N0,N1,N2, and P0,P1,P2 aren't initialized in your first iteration, but you use their value for the calulation of the Ks

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much. I guess I should change the order of K's,M's,N's and  P's. Your answer was very helpful